# how to disable datagridview mouse click event for headers in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, click, mouse

I am trying to get value out of datagridview on mouse click event.

Works great until I click on headers in datagridview. I get an error saying:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:index
```

I use this code to detect mouse click:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index != -1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

> "dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index != -1"
>   doesn't work and I do not know why.

Any easy solution to disable mouse click event on headers would be great! Thanks!

I also use:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

to select whole column and CellContentClick doesn't work. If I am lucky, CEllContentClick works 3/10 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try writing this instead:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had to change if statement to : if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1), because I also use dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect; and it wasn't just RowIndex problem was ColumnIndex problem too :) Thanks again!